# django rest datatables, filter experts by meeting objectives

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, datatables

I need to filter all Experts by past objectives.

I have a minimal runnable example at https://github.com/morenoh149/django-rest-datatables-relations-example (btw there are fixtures you can load with test data).

my models are

```
class Expert(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=300)


class Meeting(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    expert = models.ForeignKey(Expert, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    objective = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

my datatables javascript

```
$("#table-analyst-search").DataTable({
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: "/api/experts/?format=datatables",
  ordering: false,
  pagingType: "full_numbers",
  responsive: true,
  columns: [
    {
      data: "objectives",
      name: "objectives",
      visible: false,
      searchable: true,
      render: (objectives, type, row, meta) => {
        return objectives;
      }
    },
  ],
});
```

My serializer

```
class ExpertSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    objectives = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Expert
        fields = (
            "id",
            "objectives",
        )


    def get_objectives(self, obj):
        request = self.context["request"]
        request = self.context["request"]
        meetings = Meeting.objects.filter(
            analyst_id=request.user.id, expert_id=obj.id
        ).distinct('objective')
        if len(meetings) > 0:
            objectives = meetings.values_list("objective", flat=True)
            objectives = [x for x in objectives if x]
        else:
            objectives = []
        return objectives
```

When I begin to type in the datatables.js searchbar I get an error like

```
FieldError at /api/experts/
Cannot resolve keyword 'objectives' into field. Choices are: bio, company, company_id, created_at, description, email, favoriteexpert, first_name, id, is_blocked, last_name, meeting, middle_name, network, network_id, position, updated_at

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/experts/?format=datatables&draw=3&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=tags&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=favoriteexpert.tags.name&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=desc&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%
```

fwiw, in pure django orm what I want to accomplish would be something like

```
Expert.objects.filter(
    pk__in=Meeting.objects.filter(
        objective__icontains='Plastics', user=request.user
    ).values('expert')
)
```

How can I filter experts by historical meeting objectives?

[image: app and error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up authoring a custom django-filter

```
class AssociatedMeetingCharFilter(filters.CharFilter):
    def global_q(self):
        """
        Uses the global filter to search a meeting field of meetings owned by the logged in user
        """
        if not self._global_search_value:
            return Q()
        kw = "meeting__{}__{}".format(self.field_name, self.lookup_expr)
        return Q(**{
            kw: self._global_search_value,
            "meeting__user_id": self.parent.request.user.id or -1,
        })


class ExpertGlobalFilterSet(DatatablesFilterSet):
    name = GlobalCharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    objectives = AssociatedMeetingCharFilter(field_name='objective', lookup_expr='icontains')
```

full example at https://github.com/morenoh149/django-rest-datatables-relations-example

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that `django-rest-framework-datatables` is trying to translate the request into a query which can be run against the `Expert` table.

In your JS, you're asking for a field called 'objectives' to be returned, but there is no such field on the `Expert` model.

You could probably achieve what you are trying to do using the [`django-filter` integration](https://django-rest-framework-datatables.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django-filters.html).  In this case, you could set up a filter on the FK reference to the `Meeting` table. The [example app](https://django-rest-framework-datatables.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#a-more-complex-and-detailed-example) demonstrates how to do this.

I think the best way to understand what's going on is to get the example application running, and if possible, set breakpoints and step through.

Incidentally, if you want to get the search box to work correctly, then you need to define a `global_q()` method.  This is also covered in the example app.